# How to iterate over several option vectors in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have several option vectors' references over `Rc` pointers to trait objects and I'd like to iterate over all their items.

Basically, declaration of those vectors looks like this:

```rust
let vec_0: Option<&Vec<Rc<TraitObject>>> = ...;
let vec_1: Option<&Vec<Rc<TraitObject>>> = ...;
...
let vec_n: Option<&Vec<Rc<TraitObject>>> = ...;
```

I tried using `chain()` method like this:

```rust
let it = vec_o.unwrap_or(&vec![]).iter()
    .chain(vec_1.unwrap_or(&vec![]))
    ...
    .chain(vec_n.unwrap_or(&vec![]));

for el in it {
    ...
}
```

But there was a problem with this code, as those empty vectors are temporary objects that'd be deleted by the time the iterator is used.

Right now I've done it the straigtforward way:

```rust
let mut vector = vec![];
if let Some(vc) = vec_0 {
    vector.extend(vc.iter())
}

if let Some(vc) = vec_1 {
    vector.extend(vc.iter())
}

...

if let Some(vc) = vec_n {
    vector.extend(vc.iter())
}

for el in vector {
    ...
}
```

This one looks cumbersome and not that convenient for reading.

Is there any way to iterate through all elements of `vec_0`, `vec_1`, etc. easier? I am a newbie in Rust, and it seems to me that there must be solution with `chain()` method.

Any help will be appreciated =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Iterator`'s API to do that pretty easily:

```rust
fn main() {
    let vec_0 = Some(vec![7, 8, 9]);
    let vec_1 = Some(vec![1, 2, 3]);
    let vec_2 = None;
    let vec_3 = Some(vec![4, 5, 6]);

    let all = [vec_0, vec_1, vec_2, vec_3]; // [Option<Vec<i32>>; 3]

    for i in all
        .iter()
        // Filter out the None yielding an iterator of &Vec<i32>
        .flat_map(|f| f)
        // Yields an iterator of iterator of i32
        .map(|v| v.iter())
        // Flatten this iterator into a single iterator of i32
        .flatten()
    {
        println!("i = {}", i);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use `.flat_map (|v| v.iter())` instead of `.map (|v| v.iter()).flatten()`

Comment: Thank you! This solution worked well for me =)
@Jmb And thank you for the idea of how to make it even better!

Comment: Can someone explain to me how flat_map filters the None values?  I'm looking at https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map and don't see anything about filtering there.

Comment: @AlexKing `Option` is iterable itself, yielding one element of it is `Some` and zero if it is `None`.